# Date Conversion Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, date

having a bit of a head scratching moment.

```
RTrim(To_Char(startdate, 'Day')) || ' ' || To_Char(startdate, 'DD') || ' ' || RTrim(To_Char(startdate, 'Month')) || ' ' || To_Char(startdate, 'YYYY') interviewDate

Which displays in Oracle as: Thursday 14 August 2008
```

Though I am struggling to replicate this in SQL Server. I've tried DATEPART but I'm not even getting close the right answer.

Many thanks to all who reply.

Comment: As an aside, your Oracle is identical to `select to_char(startdate, 'fmDay DD Month YYYY') from dual`, which is a lot simpler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SELECT @Date = GETDATE()

SELECT DATENAME(weekday, @Date)+ ' ' + DATENAME(d, @Date) + ' ' + DATENAME(m, @Date) + ' ' + DATENAME(yyyy, @Date)
```

Output:

```
Monday 29 April 2013
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DATENAME (DW, startdate) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),startdate,106)
```